# Seeking updated pgRouting Tutorial?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, routing, references

Is there an updated pGRouting tutorial to this:

https://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/

Trying to following it using QGIS 2.14.0 Essen +  PostgreSql 9.5 (pgAdmin III) but can't get it to produce the query output result route, in fact there is not result from running the query (0 rows)

Comment: The tutorial is still valid.  Your problem is probably more related to the query.  Make sure the IDs you are passing to pgr_dijkstra exist.  Please edit your question to include the SQL query you are using for us to examine.

Comment: Thanks,you were right that was it. The shp i had downloaded of the network for Vienna only contained IDs 1 to 2123 hence why passing 1 to 3000 through pgr_dijkstra didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Shape file for the public transport network of Vienna wasn't as per one used in the tutorial, it didn’t contain the same amount of attributes which resulted in no result when trying to pass IDs 1 to 3000 through pgr_dijkstra.